# Tcl Tk show all available links

Tags: url, hyperlink, tree, tcl, tk-toolkit

Is there a function in Tcl/Tk to show all available urls from a link? I want to start to programm a webcrawler with some features.

```
For example:
the user types this:
"www.testsite.com"
and he will get that:
"www.testsite.com/dir1/"
"www.testsite.com/dir2/"
e.g.
```

Or is it better to programm it with other language like phyton?

br

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy to do with the http and tDOM packages. You just need to know a bit of XPath…

```
package require http
package require tdom

set tok [http::geturl http://example.com/index.html]
set html [http::data $tok]
http::cleanup $tok

set doc [dom parse -html $html]
foreach anchor [$doc selectNodes "//a"] {
    puts [$anchor @href]
}
```

Comment: It appears to work when I run it against my corporate intranet front page, though I don't think I'll distribute the link list…

Comment: If the document has `a` elements without `href` attributes (name anchors, for instance), one can use `foreach href [$doc selectNodes {//a/@href}] {puts [lindex $href end]}`.

Comment: @PeterLewerin I _think_ the XPath in that case would best be `//a[@href]`; you don't want the attribute nodes, you just want to specify that they're there.

Comment: That works too. When I just want the value of the attribute and don't care about the node, I do it as in my previous comment.

Comment: It's just that attribute nodes are weird in DOM and I try to avoid looking at them directly. ;-)

Comment: What I get is a list with a name and a value, not a node object?